# How to clone repository with password via bash script

Tags: git, bash, github

There is private repo on github. I have SSH key and password.
How can I pre-include password via bash-script to avoid password input in password form?

For now I have following:

```
git clone " + repository + " " + path
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to do it:

1- If you are going to run from a single machine, you can make it a trusted machine by [setting up your SSH key](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys).

2- Using curl with this command (by replacing username, password and repoName with your desired parameters):

```
curl -u 'username:password' https://api.github.com/user/repos -d '{"name":"repoName"}'
```

3- [Here](https://gist.github.com/mdashti/2007c6663d055792e509) is a sample bash script, which can be further extended and used for more sophisticated operations.

Comment: as for https I already know it. I am wondering about "git" protocol.

Comment: Did you have a look at number 3? You can use the [gist](https://gist.github.com/mdashti/2007c6663d055792e509) and replace the last command (git pull) with any other command that you want.